# Angular 2 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found)

Tags: angularjs, angular

I need to add google charts to my project through this->https://github.com/vimalavinisha/angular2-google-chart

I followed each and every step.But I'm getting this error from SystemJs.I have found some answers (2-3 months old), but they did not work for me.(Angular 2)

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
   "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "typings":"^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

systemjs.config.js----

```
(function (global) {
   System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

tsConfig.json---

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

and finally app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { GoogleChart } from 'angular2-google-chart/directives/angular2-google-chart.directive';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ,GoogleChart],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is the error I'm getting ->Error loading http://localhost:3000/angular2-google-chart/directives/angular2-google-chart.directive as "angular2-google-chart/directives/angular2-google-chart.directive

I could not find any answer which works,I have already lost a lot of hours to this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by my self. I have created my own Directive and copy-paste the source from angular2-google-chart.diretive.ts file. it worked for me that the only way it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As i look at the sample systemjs.config.js you shared it still is missing the `directives` attribute in `map` and `packages`.

Here how it looks from the github file https://github.com/vimalavinisha/angular2-google-chart/blob/master/systemjs.config.js

```
 var map = {
    ...
    'directives' : 'directives/'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
     ...
    'directives':{ defaultExtension: 'js' } 
  };
```

Comment: You should have a directives folder next to node_modules folder with the scripts defined for this library